# VBA: Function comparing SUMIFS on different columns of a range and returning Min or Max according to a boolean

Tags: vba, function, sumifs, ranged-loops

I am trying to get to a sumifs with two parameters on an important set of columns (# of columns won´t change, data will), and then return the max or the min

```
Function min_or_max(B As Boolean, table As Range, col1 As Range, c1 As Cell, col2 As Range, c2 As Cell)
Dim column As Range

'If B = False Then
min_or_max = 0
For Each column In Range.Columns
If ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.column, col1, c1, col2, c2) > min_or_max Then
min_or_max = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.column, col1, c1, col2, c2)
End If
Next column

'Elsif B = True
'min_or_max = 10000000
'For Each column In Range.Columns
'If ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.Columns(i), col1, c1, col2, c2) < min_or_max Then
'min_or_max = ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.Columns(i), col1, c1, col2, c2)
'End If
'Next column
End Function
```

Before even do the split min or max, I can´t get the SUMIFS to work. Is it because of bad argements entry?
(i hope that clear!)

Thanks a lot to whoever can help me!
drf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `WorksheetFunction` is not a **Worksheet object**, but an **Application object**.

So, you would want to use `Application.Worksheetfunction`

#### This line:

```
If ActiveSheet.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.column, col1, c1, col2, c2) > min_or_max Then
```

Needs to look like this:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range.column, col1, c1, col2, c2) > min_or_max Then
```

Comment: Thanks! it is something I had trouble understanding. But i changed it and it still doesn't work: I get #!Value (even getting the For Each and the If loops out)

Comment: @draynaud Sorry, I don't ever remember seeing the first ping for some reason, or I'd help earlier :(

Comment: No worries, I think what u added helped me a lot. I did it in two different functions without the boolean, but it is working brillantly, and a lot faster than with 2 Integers loop!

Answer (score 1):

For now i am using a very basic and SLOW solution:

```
Function max_table(table As range, col1 As range, c1 As range, col2 As range, c2 As range)
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim prov As Integer

max_table = 0
For i = 1 To table.Columns.Count
prov = 0
For j = 1 To table.Rows.Count
    If col1(j).Value = c1.Value And col2(j).Value = c2.Value Then
    prov = prov + table.Cells(j, i).Value
    End If
Next j
If max_table < prov Then
max_table = prov
End If
Next i

End Function
```